# Connect two tables and count reservations per time slot

Tags: php, mysql

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b729e5/1

In my reservation-system users should be able to sign up to multiple events at different time slots, each time slot has a limit of participants.

How can I connect these two tables in one MySQL-Query to get the number of places reserved per time slot of an event?

This data will be sent to php to show the user on a reservation page which time slot has free places and which is already booked up.

Comment: Replace these "tables" with their actual CREATE TABLE scripts. Add some sample data as INSERT INTO scripts and show desired result for this data with explanations.

Comment: You can use a website such as db-fiddle.com for creating you sample tables. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Comment: I am not seeing why you need to join,,

Answer (score 0):

you may change the design of the reservations Table to be like this :
reservation_id | user_id | date_of_reservation | event_id | time_slot

then multiple reservations can be multiple rows for the same user ,
then link the two tables  reservations and events using user_id + event_id

to test that your data is gethered correctly :

```
select r.user_id,r.event_id,r.time_slot,e.title
from reservations r,events e
where r.user_id = e.user_id
```

after that you can device your SQL easily using group by and count

```
select count(event_id)
from reservations r
where r.user_id = '<specific user>'
/*if you want*/
and time_slot between '' and ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your table structure first by adding another table like "EventTimeSlot".

> Event -> id | host_id | date_of_event | title | description |

> EventTimeSlot -> id | event_id | time_slot_name | max_participants |

> Reservation -> id | user_id | date_of_reservation | event_id | time_slot_id |

Then make your question clear as I did not understand what you meant by "to get the number of places reserved per time slot of an event?".